# PowerShell returns different results when being run from C# or console

Tags: c#, powershell, return-value

For the command `Get-MsolDomain` the `Status` property  (appears to be a string) returns as 'verified', but when the same command is executed from C# via `PowerShell.Invoke()` it returns as integer. It's the case with many commands and properties.

How can I get the string with `Status` property instead of integer?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement most likely returns a value from an enum. Enumeration elements have a string and an integer representation, the latter of which can be accessed via the nested property `value__`.

Take for instance the [`System.DayOfWeek`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) enum:

```
PS C:\> $dow = [enum]::GetValues([type]'System.DayOfWeek')
PS C:\> $dow
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
PS C:\> $dow | % { '{0}: {1}' -f $_.value__, $_ }
0: Sunday
1: Monday
2: Tuesday
3: Wednesday
4: Thursday
5: Friday
6: Saturday
PS C:\> $dow | % { [int]$_ }
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

By default an enum element is displayed as a string, but if you use its `value__` property or put it in a context where it's cast to an integer you get the integer representation instead of the string representation.

For further information see [this Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26436.how-to-create-and-use-enums-in-powershell.aspx).